# Differential Equations Was abe to show $y'=-4x$ $y''=-4$ and when substitute $=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$(1-x^2)y''-xy'+4y=0$ Show that $1-2x^2$ is a solution try to find another using Wronskian method.

Was abe to show $y'=-4x$ $y''=-4$ and when substitute $=0$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

There are two ways to calculate the Wronskian

$$\begin{align}
&(1)~W(y_1,y_2)(t)~=~\begin{vmatrix}y_1(t) & y_2(t)\\y_1'(t) & y_2'(t)\end{vmatrix}~=~y_1(t)y_2'(t)-y_2(t)y_1'(t)\\
&(2)~W(y_1,y_2)(t)~=~e^{-\int p(x)\mathrm{d}x}
\end{align}$$

You already know one solution, $y_1$, of the differential equation.

Comment: What is $p$ in your case? I think you should include it.

Comment: The coefficient of the first derivative in the normal form, when I remember it right. In this case $p(x)=-\frac{x}{1-x^2}$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** With $p(x)=\dfrac{-x}{1-x^2}$ we write
$$W(x)=\exp\left(-\int\dfrac{-x}{1-x^2}\right)dx=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$$
for $|x|<1$. Then solve the integral
$$y_2=(1-2x^2)\int\dfrac{W(x)}{(1-2x^2)^2}dx$$

Comment: does the negative flip the equation. 1/sqrt(x^2-1) ???

Comment: I don't understand your mean. With $|x|<1$ then $W(x)=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$ and for $|x|>1$ then $W(x)=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{x^2-1}}$.